# database in install folder cannot be accessed in win 10 anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, windows-10

I have a WPF application including a SQLite Database.
Everything worked file as long as the computer was Win 7.
Since the PC is Win 10 I cannot write the database anymore because it is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName.

If I understood that right I need admin rights to write to the database in this folder. But if the program is started as administrator Drag&Drop is forbidden which I also need.

The first Idea would be to copy the database to C:\Users\\AppData\Local. There I have write access even without admin rights. But the use case of this database is that different Users on the same PC can enter this database. Thats not possible anymore if the db is installed in a personal folder.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could copy the database to C:\Users\Public\AppData\Local  Note the Public instead of user name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8  I think that's CommonApplicationData

Comment: C:\Users\Public\AppData is no valid path in win 10.

I tried C:\Users\Public\Documents and C:\ProgramData.

To both paths I have only read access.

Comment: There's not necessarilly a path if you don't create it. I think many apps use ProgramData which is what is returned on win10 from Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData); In that there is usually a organisation name\appname\version structure